# Updating the text in the same xml file using shell script

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

Using the following I can generate the XML with updated text:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u 'value to change' -v newValue source.xml
```

But how can I make changes to the same file and save it?
I need to run `xmlstarlet` a couple of times to make changes in the same file.

Comment: Use `-L` (or `--inplace`) to update the file in place.